# HTTP/1.1 status headers, when to use which?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-status-codes, http-status-code-401, http-status-code-400

Okay, I am working on an admin panel right now, so I came across stumbling, kind of.

Form: http://pastebin.com/D8Dt6zP5

Processing Page: http://pastebin.com/FpXSziPM

Now, onto the problem, I just used 403 Forbidden header when the expected values weren't found in the $_GET, but, when thought for, it isn't really an action that requires login(not for this, ofcourse a user have to login to view the admin panel in the first place), it's more like an unexpected value input.

So I have gone and made a research, in the brief explanations of each, I elected these headers which might be suitable.

I refer from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), looking out by groups of each status code, this should belong in 4XX codes.

So going deeper, and I elect these two:

`400 Bad Request:` The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax

`417 Expectation Failed:` The server cannot meet the requirements of the Expect request-header field

Now, I cannot be really sure which one to use, I have seen `400 Bad Request` being used alot, however, whatI get from explanation is that the error is due to an unexistent request rather than an illegal input.

On the other side `417 Expectation Failed` seems to just fit for my use, however, I have never seen or experimented this header status before.

*As I side note, as of the explanation in Wikipedia for 403, I can see it's extremely wrong for this, like I thought, I should probably be using 401 for the views without login, and 403 for a logged user which doesn't have access to a certain area.*

So I really need your opinions, thanks by now.

Regards, TheDeadLike.

Comment: Great question, but you might have better luck with it over on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks for the reference it really helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer; thanks for the interest.

You can see the answer [here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/433470/http-1-1-status-codes-400-and-417-cannot-choose-which)